# Как задать координаты массива в input-е Js

Tags: javascript

Написал функцию, которая рисует таблицу и передал в нее массив. С помощью *input* можно рисовать строки и столбцы. Ещё добавил два *input* и кнопку для того, чтобы задавать координаты (ну знаете на подобие игры 'морской бой'). Как это сделать? Например ввожу значение "2" "3" ( второй столбец и 3 строка) и выводилось там значение "1"

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if (document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0) {
    for (var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove();
    };
  };

  table.classList.add('_Table');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="col3">
<input type="text" class="col4">
<button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте сначала `id` для ваших ячеек таблицы:

```
tableData.forEach(function(rowData,i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData,j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.id=i+'_'+j
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });
```

тогда вы без проблем их найдете по `id`:

```
   var gell = document.getElementById(row+"_"+col);
   gell.innerHTML="1"
```

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if(document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0){
    for(var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove(); 
    };
  };
  
  table.classList.add('_Table');
  
  tableData.forEach(function(rowData,i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData,j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.id=i+'_'+j
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});

document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
   var row = document.querySelector(".col3").value;
   var col = document.querySelector(".col4").value;
   var gell = document.getElementById(row+"_"+col);
   gell.innerHTML="1"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
  <input type="text" class="col2">
   <button class="btn">Go</button>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" class="col3">
   <input type="text" class="col4">
   <button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку бро

Comment: @Anton Если координаты задать верно, то не выдает. Задачи сделать проверку координат не было.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), событие можно обработать так:

```
object.addEventListener("change", function(e) { doThingsWith(e.target.value) } )
```

Или поместить в форму и обработать `submit`.

А получить значение ячейки по координатам поможет такое свойство html-таблиц:

```
table.rows[rowIndex].cells[columnIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант высчитывать ячейку, непосредственно, через позиции указанные во вторых полях по индексу элементов:

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if (document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0) {
    for (var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove();
    };
  };

  table.classList.add('_Table');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});

// Вот код
document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var stings = document.querySelector('.col3').value,
      rows = document.querySelector('.col4').value;
  document.querySelectorAll('._Table > tbody > tr')[stings - 1].querySelectorAll('td')[rows - 1].innerHTML = 1;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="col3">
<input type="text" class="col4">
<button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```